# Nodejs app on Heroku "error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, heroku, spawn, heroku-cli, libffi

I have an executable file called "Main" that I want to run in a node app on heroku. In order to do that I use this function

```
function run(code, params) {
  const { execFileSync } = require('child_process');
  const child = execFileSync('/app/Main', params ? [code, params] : [code], {
    timeout: timeout * 1000,
    cwd: __dirname,
    stdio: 'pipe',
  })
  if (child.status === null) {
    return `child status null`
  }
  return child.stdout.toString()
}
```

But it gives me this error back.

```
./Main: error while loading shared libraries: libffi.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also receive this error when I run

```
heroku run bash -a "appname"
```

and then try to

```
./Main
```

Is there any way to work around this? From my experience, the heroku file system is very restricted and is mostly read only access. Can I somehow curl an older version to its correct place with a .profile or anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to compile the binary file from a ubuntu version that uses libffi7 not libffi6 and also load libffi7 in an .Aptfile at the root directory for heroku